# linking error with cmake project for bare metal target

Tags: c++, cmake, bare-metal

I'm trying to make a CMAKE script for my bare metal project. The target is a STM32F4, arch-linux like host.

I used this **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
IF(WIN32)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
ELSE(WIN32)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)
ENDIF(WIN32)
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)


# set cross compilation information
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

# specify the toolchain
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)
#set(CMAKE_LD ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}ld)

set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}as)
set(CMAKE_AR ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objdump)

CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-g++ GNU)

#specify the linker
#SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld)
#SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld)
#SET(CMAKE_LINKER /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld)


set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

enable_language(ASM)

# set compiler flags
set(CPU "-mcpu=cortex-m4")
set(FPU "-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp")
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "-mthumb ${CPU} ${FPU} -MD")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mthumb ${CPU} ${FPU} -std=gnu99 -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -Wall -pedantic ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-mthumb ${CPU} ${FPU} -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti")

# set linker flags
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS "")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS "")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS " -specs=rdimon.specs -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon")


# The directory with all the FindXXX modules
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

# The macro below forces the build directory to be different from source directory:
INCLUDE( MacroEnsureOutOfSourceBuild )
MACRO_ENSURE_OUT_OF_SOURCE_BUILD(
    "${PROJECT_NAME} requires an out of source build."
)

SET(PROJECT_NAME "R")

# Start a project.
PROJECT(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Find packages
#FIND_PACKAGE(YARP REQUIRED)

# Header files
#INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${YARP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(thd)

# Shared libraries
#SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${YARP_LIBRARIES})

# Some debug information
MESSAGE("${PROJECT_NAME} is using CXX flags: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
MESSAGE ("Libraries included: ${LIBS}")

# Search for source code.
FILE(GLOB folder_source src/*.cpp src/*.cc src/*.c thd/inv/*.cpp thd/eigenvalues/*.cpp)
FILE(GLOB folder_header inc/*.h thd/inv/*.h thd/eigenvalues/*.h src/*.h)

SOURCE_GROUP("Source Files" FILES ${folder_source})
SOURCE_GROUP("Header Files" FILES ${folder_header})

# Automatically add include directories if needed.
FOREACH(header_file ${folder_header})
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(p ${header_file} PATH)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${p})
ENDFOREACH(header_file ${folder_header})

# Testing
# enable_testing()
# add_subdirectory(harness)

# Set up our main executable.
IF (folder_source)
   ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${folder_source} ${folder_header})
   TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
   install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)   
ELSE (folder_source)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "No source code files found. Please add something")
ENDIF (folder_source)
```

and this **Makefile**:

```
#!/bin/make -f

all:
    mkdir -p build
    cd build && cmake ..
    cd build && make all

clean:
    cd build && make clean


.PHONY: all clean
```

When i did "make" i got these linking errors after the compiling of all fles work:

```
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/R.dir/thd/eigenvalues/blas.obj
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/R.dir/thd/eigenvalues/hsschur.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable R
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
abort.c:(.text.abort+0x10): undefined reference to `_exit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_fstat'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-openr.o): In function `_open_r':
openr.c:(.text._open_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_open'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_kill'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x4): undefined reference to `_getpid'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_write'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-gettimeofdayr.o): In function `_gettimeofday_r':
gettimeofdayr.c:(.text._gettimeofday_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_gettimeofday'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_lseek'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_read'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/R.dir/build.make:484: recipe for target 'R' failed
make[3]: *** [R] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory
```

I don't get it why, since with these linker flags `-specs=rdimon.specs -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon` I should be able to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: If you try  `--specs=rdimon.specs` (note the double-flag) does it work?

Answer (score 5):

You are compiling bare-metal application, there are no OS services underneath. It means the compiler has no means to perform certain operations such as exit (abnormal termination due to assertion or exception), write the error message to the standard output/error, etc... It means you have to provide such services yourself. Usually they are empty stubs, or redirecting the write attempts to proper UART device used for debugging.

I would recommend reading [Practical Guide to Bare Metal C++](https://alex-robenko.gitbook.io/bare_metal_cpp/) and chapter [Know Your Compiler Output](https://alex-robenko.gitbook.io/bare_metal_cpp/compiler_output) in particular.

Comment: Both of these links appear to be dead.